# If $z$ is a complex number and $|z| = 1$ and $z^2 \neq 1$. Then $\frac{z}{1-z^2}$ lies on :-

Tags: complex-numbers, problem-solving

> If $z$ is a complex number and $|z| = 1$ and $z^2 \neq 1$. Then $\frac{z}{1-z^2}$ lies on :-

$(a)$ A line not through origin. 
$(b)$ $|z| = 2$. 
$(c)$ $x$-axis. 
$(d)$ $y$-axis.

**What I Tried**:-

From [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2128983_find_the_where_the_complex_number_z1z2_lies_on) in the AOPS site, I understood that just bashing it gives us the solution I am looking for, but I want a solution without bashing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't understand what "bashing" means in this context."What I tried" in fact...  you have tried nothing.  Please prove you have worked on this issue.

Comment: I think it just means that you put $z=x+iy$ and "bash" everything out

Comment: Hint: Write denominator as $ |z|^2 - z^2 = z \cdot \bar z - z^2$

Comment: @DatBoi: To be fair, that is also an standard way to solve the problem, the other way being using identities stated above.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 In fact it is pretty straightforward in this case to expand and solve.

Comment: @MathLover, I think you should make that an answer. It seems the fastest way to see that the expression is purely imaginary.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I would have but the question was destined to be closed and so I left it as a hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
w=\frac{z}{1-z^2}&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{1+z}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}-1}-\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}+1}\right]\\
&=\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}^2-1}\\
&=-\bar{w}\\
w+\bar{w}&=0.
\end{align*}
Thus $\Re{(w)}=0$. This means $w$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Another approach to check if a complex number is imaginary, if you don't know a factorization to use, is to add it to its complex conjugate. Using $|z|=1$, you'd get that the sum is zero.

Comment: @Joe While that is true, but there was no way of knowing when I started it that is what we will end up getting :-)

Comment: Oh, I guess I was using the fact that the question is multiple choice. Letting $z=i$ rules out (b) and (c), so I next checked if the expression was pure imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z| = 1$, the $z$ can be represented in a trigonometic form as

$$
z = e^{i\theta} = \cos{(\theta)} + i\sin{\theta}.
$$

Given $z^2 \ne 1$, it means that $\theta \ne \pi n, n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{z}{1-z^2} &= \frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{2i\theta}} = \frac{\cos{(\theta)} + i\sin{\theta}}{(1 - \cos{(2\theta)}) - i\sin{2\theta}} = \\
&= \frac{(\cos{(\theta)} + i\sin{\theta})((1 - \cos{(2\theta)}) + i\sin{2\theta})}{(1 - \cos{(2\theta)})^2 + \sin^2{2\theta}} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Simplify this expression, extract real and imaginary parts, and you will see that only imaginary part is not 0, which means that $\frac{z}{1-z^2}$ lies on $y$-axis.